# PHP installed--code not working in browser

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I have installed PHP and its not working in the Apache Webserver.

Steps followed

1. Installed Apache and tested a sample html file and it worked fine.
2. Installed PHP and configured in apache.
3. Created a new php file under httd folder and tried running through the browser but it just opens with the code.

PHP code:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

There were many recomendations to install WAMP Server. My next step would be that but I just want to fix it.:)

Comment: First question, how exactly did you configure Apache for PHP. And second, did you restart Apache after the configuration?

Comment: Have you gone to it as http://localhost/path/to/file.php? Or opened it by double clicking on it?

Comment: Unless you really want the experience setting up Apache, PHP, etc, I'd definitely second the recommendation to just install WAMP/XAMPP. If you don't want the experience managing a server, it's a *much* simpler process to get things working, everything should just work out of the box. Setting up an Apache/PHP server from scratch can take a while, a good deal of manual configuration, and a lot of reading if you've no prior experience.

Comment: @Perception  I opened the apache config file and gave the following commands, 
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php 
PHPIniDir "C:/php"             ..I also restarted once its configured

Comment: @Corbin I tried both ways ie; double clicking as well to accessing the file from browser

Comment: @corbin this http://localhost/ is not working from the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RECOMENDED IS XAMPP http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html

for your problem if your are running SKYPE On windows make sure you sign out cause they share the same port 80 
or any other program that might do the same